# About exceptions on Session Bean

Tags: java, ejb, session-bean

I am reading the book. It said the `Singleton session bean` will never be re-created in the event of a system exception, unlike other kind of session beans. So, I have some questions.

1. Will both of `stateless` and `stateful` session beans be re-created in the event of a system exception ?
2. When the `singleton` session bean instance encounters exceptions, could it continue to work well to response other requests ?

Comment: I am assuming you mean if the Singleton throws an exception in its construction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Stateless beans are created for every method call as necessary. Stateful beans will be destroyed, and the client needs to explicitly create a new one.
2. Yes, singleton beans are never destroyed, so the same instance will be used for subsequent method calls even when beans of another type would be destroyed.